# Does the ALU contain predefined functions?

Tags: cpu

So the ALU has logic gates inside of it that preform operations on binary data.

My question is, does the ALU have predefined logic gates in it to say, add numbers, or does it get configured to do so when it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding numbers is such a basic feature of an Arithmetic Logic Unit that yes, it will have predefined logic gates in it to do that. Fixed point division is more complex, and an old ALU that provided fixed-point division might do so by using micro-coded addition operations.

A modern ALU that provides fixed-point division will probably also have that as predefined logic gates, because logic is so small and cheap now, but might still use microcoded instructions for floating point division -- but probably won't do so to any great extent, because the whole point of buying an ALU with floating point division is to get one that does it fast, so the actual division part of the floating-point division will probably be using predefined logic gates.

Things that are likely to be micro-coded in modern processors are register-transfer commands: for example, stuff that does 64 bit division using a hard-coded 32 bit divider would need to move the data around internally to get the words in the right order at the right time in the right place.

There are processors that allow you to dynamically configure at the gate level, but they aren't called Arithmetic Logic Units, and they aren't used for general-purpose computing.

Answer (score 0):

"Configured when it needs to be" saves a lot of parts and power. Arithmetic emerges from the XOR of a Manchester Carry Chain with a Karnaugh map. Almost no-one does this, but i8086 did. Not with relays obviously...

ALU with Series Prefixed Magnitude Comparator:

[image: Diagram]